# Update a range of values from one column into a specific range of values of another column on another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables that are very different and have *no column they can be inner joined on*.

I want to do an insert operation on both, one after the other, but one of the columns of the second table needs to have the ID (both tables have an "ID" column that is the IDENTITY) values of the newly inserted rows of the first table.

The only solution I was able to come up with was to use a cursor or create two temporary tables to act as intermediary and drop them after.

I was wondering if there was a smarter solution to this.

Example data:

```
Table1
ID   Name    Email
1    John    john@aol.com
2    Mary    mary@aol.com
3    Sue      sue@aol.com
4    John    john@aol.com
5    Jim      jim@aol.com
6    Chris  chris@aol.com

Table2
ID Table1ID   Job
1  4          Manager
2  5          Printer
3  6          Dev
```

What must be done is insert the data:

```
Bob bob@aol.com
Amy amy@aol.com
Tom tom@aol.com
```

into Table1, while the data

```
TeamLead
Manager
Dev
```

is inserted into Table2, along with the Table1 IDs which will be created for the Bob, Amy and Tom records. I.e. "7, 8, 9".

Expected result:

```
Table1
ID   Name    Email
1    John    john@aol.com
2    Mary    mary@aol.com
3    Sue      sue@aol.com
4    John    john@aol.com
5    Jim      jim@aol.com
6    Chris  chris@aol.com
7    Bob      bob@aol.com
8    Amy      amy@aol.com
9    Tom      tom@aol.com

Table2
ID Table1ID   Job
1  4          Manager
2  5          Printer
3  6          Dev
4  7          TeamLead
5  8          Manager
6  9          Dev
```

Comment: *no column they can be inner joined on* doesn't make any sense when you follow it with *but one of the columns of the second table needs to have the ID values of the newly inserted rows of the first table.* But yes, there are much smarter solutions other than a cursor for **almost** everything in SQL. Sample data and expected results would help a lot

Comment: Is ID an `identity` field?

Comment: @Xedni, yes ID is an identity field, I will amend the question.

Comment: @scsimon, bad design, certainly, but it needs to be done. I will amend the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `output` clause during your insert to capture the identity values which were just inserted. I have no idea what your data looks like, but maybe this will give you the tools to adapt to your scenario

```
-- Table with identities you want to capture
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#TableWithId') is not null drop table #TableWithId
create table #TableWithId
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    SomeData varchar(36)

)
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#OtherTable') is not null drop table #OtherTable
create table #OtherTable
(
    ID int,
    SomeData varchar(36)

)
-- Output the inserted data including newly created identity fields directly into another table
insert into #TableWithId 
(
    SomeData
)
output 
    inserted.ID, 
    inserted.SomeData
into #OtherTable
(
    ID,
    SomeData
)
-- Fake source data
select top 1000 newid()
from sys.objects
```

Comment: This "output" clause seems great, but how do I make it take only the IDs of the inserted rows and insert them along with new information into Table2 ?

Comment: That depends; you said you couldn't join the two sets of data together, so I can't suggest a specific sql statement that will get the job done. However assuming those rules exist, I would simply use the `output` clause to insert the newly created IDs (along with whatever other relevant information you need to capture), and then perform updates against that temp table to fill in the additional fields you need to populate in table 2